# "Not to go to X" or "To not go to X"?

Tags: grammar, word-order, grammaticality-in-context

> 1. Dad is looking for an excuse not to go to the wedding.
> 2. Dad is looking for an excuse to not go to the wedding.

I don't know whether or not they are correct. Both sentences are found in my language learning app and sometimes the sentence isn't following the grammatical rule, so I think it's wise to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. However "not to go" is more common than "to not go".

Google search results:
"excuse not to go"  1 330 000
"excuse to not go"  996 000

Google Ngrams:

[image]

Comment: Google Ngrams searches published and digitized books. It is unreliable for speech.

Comment: @Michael Harvey. I agree. That's why I also provided the general Google search results which shows a smaller gap between the two.